# Classic ASP ADO Setting Bookmark Causes Error

Tags: asp-classic, ado

The following classic ASP code generates an error on the line rsTemp.Bookmark = varCurrBookmark.  This appears to be fairly simplistic code and should work.  Note that I can read the bookmark but can't set it.  Also, this code will work if I uncomment the line and set the CursorLocation = 3 (use client)

ADODB.Recordset error '800a0bb9'

Arguments are of the wrong type, are out of acceptable range, or are in conflict with one another.

/app/TestBookMark.asp, line 19.

```
   <html>
        <body>
            <%
                 strConn = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=localhost\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=db;User Id=uid;Password=pwd;"
                 Set objDataConn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
                 objDataConn.Open strConn
                 strQry = "SELECT * FROM tbl"
                 Set rsTemp = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
                 'rsTemp.CursorLocation = 3
                 rsTemp.Open strQry, objDataConn,3,1

                   lngRecordCount = rsTemp.RecordCount


                 varCurrBookmark = rsTemp.Bookmark
                 rsTemp.MoveLast
                 Response.Write rsTemp.Bookmark
                 Response.Write "<BR>"
                 rsTemp.Bookmark = varCurrBookmark
                 Response.Write varCurrBookmark             
                 %>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hmmmm. It should work with that cursor type. Can you try the following after the rsTemp.Open?

Response.Write "Recordset supports bookmarks: " & rsTemp.Supports(&H2000) & "<BR>"

Comment: That will tell you if the recordset you're creating (without the client side cursor location) supports bookmarks. If it returns FALSE, I don't know why it would, and if it returns TRUE, well, you still have a problem! :-)

Comment: Just another thought to throw into the pile... Do make the check, but if it returns true, try commenting out your RecordCount statement and see if that has an effect. I'm wondering if that's affecting the cursor placement such that the bookmark assignment is problematic.

Comment: Hi Bret -- thanks for the response.  I tried what you asked and Supports Bookmarks is returning true. I removed all record movement or counting and I even tried rsTemp.Bookmark = rsTemp.Bookmark and it generates the same error "Arguments are of the wrong type, are out of acceptable range, or are in conflict with one another".  My database is SQL Server Express 2008 R2

Comment: Also setting it to a client side cursor rsTemp.CursorLocation = 3 and it works fine.  I am just wondering if this causes any performance issues.

Comment: Curious. Another semi-thoughtful flail to try: move to the first record in the recordset before setting the bookmark initially. So after the rsTemp.Open, add the following line before setting the bookmark:

rsTemp.MoveFirst

See if that addresses it.

Comment: Hi Bret -- unfortunately I think I found the anser here.  This code was from a 12 year old application that was working in a 32 bit environment fine. I believe based on the post here, it broke when we moved it to 64 bit SQL and windows. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/sqlserver/en-US/dfcf75ec-5cb3-4aae-8a8f-7cddcc26b02c/error-800a0bb9-when-accessing-bookmark-property

Comment: Interesting. I'd encourage you to summarize that (with the link) as an answer to your question so that others can find it more readily. Sorry it's kind of a dead end, but hopefully you can work around it reasonably well.